# java compiler: module not found. How to inspect module resolution?

Tags: java, java-platform-module-system

When compiling my project I get a "module not found" exception. I understand what this means: apparently I have (transitively) required a module that is not on the module path. But I have not required, used or otherwise that module, as far as I can infer.

I've inspected the module-info.java, and used jar --describe-module on all jars on the compiler's module-path and nowhere I can find that missing module even mentioned. So why does the compiler think it is missing?

If a simular situation would occur in Maven, I would dump the dependency tree and see where that dependency came from. And the java executable has a --show-module-resolution for doing this at runtime, but this does not work for the compiler.

Is there any way to get more information on why the compiler thinks a module is missing?

Comment: You can use `jdeps -s ...` to analyze the module dependency graph.

Comment: jdeps seems not very convenient, because it requires access to all jars to determine the tree (which makes sense of course). So it would require all dependencies as defined in the poms. Logically I expected a maven plugin for this, but apparently none exists yet that does this. I tried to solve this with the dependencies plugin, but I keep running to missing jars. Basically you need to resolve the dependencies in order to see the dependencies. But that makes sense, since the information is part of the jars. Although I would prefer jdeps to print what it knows instead of completely failing.

Comment: After getting jdeps to work (maven dependencies plugin copied too many jars) it seems to dump the dependencies of all jars included on the classpath, instead of creating the tree given as the starting point. Which also makes sense, because these jars are the dependencies so it would require to resolve all jars. But it does not construct a tree so you can trace the flow. But it at least is something.

Comment: Sorry it say what module you're missing? Can you try to create a [mcve]?

Comment: My question was not to solve the problem at hand, I knew I could do that (and have done) given enough time. The question was about getting information from the compiler on the modules it gathered; how and where from. Just like the dependency tree in Maven. Turns out it is not possible to ask the compiler, and the way it can be done (jdeps) does not help if there is a problem because it fails immediately upon encountering a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to ask the compiler how it constructs its modules.

As stated by Aniket, it is possible to use jdeps to analyse module dependencies. But in order to do so, jdeps needs access to all jars the compiler uses, because the dependency information is inside the jars.

There is a Maven plugin that copies all dependencies into target/dependencies. Per default it will include all scopes, including test, so one needs to be specific.

```
mvn dependency:copy-dependencies -DincludeScope=compile
```

Then you can use jdeps to analyse the modules:

```
jdeps -summary -recursive --class-path target/dependency/*
```

This will not construct a tree, but it will show what modules each module requires.

Unfortunately jdeps is not very forgiving, and will fail if only one jar is missing. IMHO it would be preferable to print what is known, including any broken reference, then fail.

Answer (score 0):

The error "Module not found" is because the Java compiler is unable to find the `module-info.java` file. I think you have to make sure it is in the right directory path. This error indicates that the module file is not available in the module path provided.

Comment: That would be very unlikely. The project (JFXtras on github) already is fully modularized and compiles, I'm only trying to make some changes. And indeed the module-info.java is present in src/main/java (I inspected it for the mentioned module). But assuming your suggestion is correct, how can the compiler come to the conclusion that a not referred module is missing? But this is not an answer to my question: I would like to see the module resolution of the compiler.